# How can I use Mat's data pointer to create a GPUMat entity?

Tags: opencv

How can I use Mat's pointer to create the GPUMat entity?

The following of my implementation is wrong.

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include "opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp"
//using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    //Mat img = imread();
    cv::Mat mSource = cv::imread("C:\\New Folder\\1.jpg");
    cv::gpu::GpuMat gpuInput(mSource.rows, mSource.cols, CV_32FC1, mSource.data, cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);       

    cv::gpu::GpuMat  mGTarget;
    cv::gpu::resize(gpuInput, mGTarget, cv::Size(0, 0), 0.5, 0.5);

    cv::Mat mTarget;
    mGTarget.download(mTarget);

    cv::imwrite("C:\\New Folder\\5.jpg", mTarget);
}
```

Comment: Why not use TAPI? https://www.learnopencv.com/opencv-transparent-api/

Answer (score 2):

Use the `GpuMat::upload` and `GpuMat::download` functions. The `upload` function takes a `cv::Mat` as parameter and uploads the host data to device.

```
GpuMat gpuInput;
gpuInput.upload(mSource);
```

Comment: @md612 Why exactly do you want to do that?

Comment: I have one similiar application which has the same problem -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658100/how-to-turn-opencv-gpumat-into-cudeviceptr/46663438?noredirect=1#comment80275867_46663438.

Comment: @md612 The decoded frame is most probably single channel YUV frame, and you're providing `CV_8UC3` as image type. You've to make sure what is the type of the decoded frame.